# Corona sdk - add developer payload to in app purchases

Tags: in-app-purchase, coronasdk, payload

I want to add a developer payload string to my in-app-purchases in corona sdk, so I can verify the purchase on a secure server. 
(http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html#payload)

Although I can't find any reference to it in the store library's documentation:
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/store/index.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You really don't have much in the way of control from the IAP servers.  You get a transaction back from the server and using the information there, including the digital receipt, you can then contact your secure server and record the local copy of the transaction using the receipt you got from Apple or Google.